# Meteor templates not recognized in server code

Tags: javascript, email, templates, meteor, server

I am building an app in Meteor and I am trying to send an email from a server-side method. The email's template exists in my client/views folder. So when I try to send an email from the server-side code, I get the error 'Template not defined'. Here's my code:

/server/methods/sendemail.js

```
var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.emailToCustomer, dataContext);
Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                 thisUser.emails[0].address,
                'mine@mine.org',
                'yours@gmail.com',
                 'email subject',
                  html
                );
```

My email template is just a simple html page. Note that this code works fine if it exists in client/views/mytemplate.js. However, for technical reasons, I need the email to be sent from server-side code.

I have tried placing the mytemplate.html and mytemplate.js files in the app/both and app/server folders, but I still get the template not defined error.

Anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templates are defined under the client directory so it's normal that they are not available in the server context.

Unfortunately it's not possible at the moment to access Blaze templates using vanilla Meteor APIs at the moment, even if you move your templates to a shared directory available to both client and server.

What you can do however is use [`meteorhacks:ssr`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) to define server only templates that you'll be able to render using the standard Spacebars syntax.

You'll need to put your server templates under the server only `private` directory and compile them in your server code using :

```
SSR.compileTemplate("emailToCustomer", Assets.getText("emailToCustomer.html"));
```

Server templates don't need the `<template>` tag, you can define them straight away :

`private/emailToCustomer.html`

```
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
<p>This is server-side rendering !</p>
```

In your server code, once the template is compiled, you can define helpers just like you would in standard client-side Blaze templating :

```
Template.emailToCustomer.helpers({
  name: function(){
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
});
```

Then you can render the template using :

```
var html = SSR.render("emailToCustomer", {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
});
```